# JavaFX limit window resize

Tags: java, javafx

i'm creating some simple app in JavaFX, and can't set windows minimum height and width - setting MinWidth and MinHeight doesn't work for me.
I found a way to do that by this code:

```
stage.getScene().widthProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if(newValue.doubleValue() >= 400.0) {
            menu.setPrefWidth(newValue.doubleValue());
            pane.setPrefWidth(newValue.doubleValue());
        } else
            stage.setWidth(400-dW);
    });

    stage.getScene().heightProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if(newValue.doubleValue() >= 470.0)
            pane.setPrefHeight(newValue.doubleValue()-menu.getHeight());
        else
            stage.setHeight(470-dH);
    });
```

But this allows to change size to smaller and then force it size to minimum allowed - but this is visible when using program. Is there possible to do that in better way?

Comment: The setMinWidth and setMinHeight methods of Stage work for me.  What version of Java are you using, and on what OS are you running?

Comment: Windows 10, had 8u20, but with 8u92 problem nothing changes ;/